# Creating textarea in Angular form - getting form cannot bind error

Tags: angular, forms, textarea

I am creating the formgroup  `psapmulticircuitsearch` with one text area (control name `'psapsearch'`)

Getting the error:
Can't bind to `'formGroup'` since it isn't a known property of `'form'`.

Here's my template file:

```
this.psapmulticircuitsearch = this.fb.group({psapsearch:['']});
```

Comment: Kiruthika, could you give a little bit more detail about your issue?

Comment: It sounds like you're missing imports for ```FormsModule``` or ```ReactiveFormsModule```.

Comment: I have added ReactiveFormsModule in app.component.ts.

Comment: I am trying to create one textarea with the form formGroup myForm. But it throw me error Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the Required Directive to Your Template:

In your component's `.component.html`, you need to make sure you're using the correct directive for the form. For reactive forms, you should use the `formGroup`directive:

```
<!-- use formGroup directive -->
<form [formGroup]="psapmulticircuitsearch"> 
  <textarea formControlName="psapsearch"></textarea>
</form>
```

It seems like you're already using FormBuilder:

You can import the `FormBuilder` service from `@angular/forms` in your component file if you haven't already. It seems like you've already used it tho:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
})
export class YourComponent {
// declare you form group variable
  psapmulticircuitsearch: FormGroup; 

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.psapmulticircuitsearch = this.fb.group({
      psapsearch: [''],
    });
  }
}
```

Hope this helps get rid of that error.

Comment: Thanks.But still getting same error

Comment: Ok interesting. Feel free to give more details of your files/more code and maybe we can figure it out.